# Gnome and Cinnamon loads in fallback (classic) mode only

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, linux-mint, cinnamon

So I have been using linux mint for a while now. A few months ago my Gnome shell crashed and I was unable to use the full 3d features and loaded into fallback mode only. From that day (around 2 months ago) I still have only fallback mode (both Gnome and cinnamon). I installed Linux mint maya, and Ubuntu 12.04 both as windows file and complete installation in an external hard drive. and for many times I sitll cannot fix this problem. ps I made sure to download all the drivers for my graphics card. what could the problem be?

Comment: What happens when you execute `gnome-shell --replace` in an xterm? Does it print any useful message?

Comment: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: You found the problem: check your X driver and verify if GLX is supported. What video card do you have? And what driver are you using in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`?

Answer (score -1):

I've got crash when using Rhythmbox, switched to amarok and everything is ok now. It may be application (not drivers) problem then.

Comment: he's not describing a crash. he's saying that 3D isn't working.

Comment: Quote from question " A few months ago my Gnome shell crashed and I was unable to use the full 3d features and loaded into fallback mode only" And I also had a crash (rhytmbox crashed) and after crash 3d stop working.